# Not able to display numeric key value in interpolation using Angular

Tags: angular

data = [
  {
    "1": 1,
    "2": 2,
    "test1": "test1",
    "test2": "test2",
    "test3": "test3",
    "test4": "test4"
  }
]

[Not able to display value for numeric keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKDZ5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `{{ item["1"] }}` as property is not a valid identifier.